# Not able to store the session id from response headers when using sessions in react/frappe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, erpnext, frappe

I am trying to fetch the session id (sid) from the response headers.

My client app is on a local environment where as my API is hosted on a server (ERP Next).

When sending the login request from React app I am able to get the response but when trying to access the response headers I am not getting any `set-cookie` key in the headers that contain the `sid` though looking at the network tab I see the `set-cookie` key in the response headers section.

What can be the problem with this, can there be an issue because of CORS policy or the same site?

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk("user/login", async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${base_url}/api/method/login?usr=username&pwd=password`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          usr: "username",
          pwd: "password",
        }),
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Login failed");
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const headersObj = Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries());
    console.log("Response headers:", headersObj);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during login:", error);
    throw error;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `sid` cookie from the `Set-Cookie` header using `response.headers.get("Set-Cookie")`.

```
fetch(`${base_url}/api/method/login`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    usr: "username",
    pwd: "password",
  }),
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const cookies = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie");
      if (cookies) {
        const sidCookie = cookies
          .split(";")
          .find((cookie) => cookie.startsWith("sid="));
        if (sidCookie) {
          const sid = sidCookie.split("=")[1];
          console.log("sid:", sid);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Authentication failed");
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```